# How to update django model based form(having choices option) records by using html form

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to update my pre existing model**(ShiftChange)** and in model based form i have used CHOICES as shown below.

```
 from django.db import models
        
     ======
=============
        )
        class ShiftChange(models.Model):
            ldap_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
            Vendor_Company = models.CharField(max_length=64,choices=VENDOR_CHOICES,default='genesys')
            EmailID =  models.EmailField(max_length=64,unique=True)
            Shift_timing = models.CharField(max_length=64,choices=SHIFT_CHOICES,default='General_Shift')
            Reason = models.TextField(max_length=256)
            # updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

And to update i'm using html based form because i wanted to display content to end user(end user will click on update button and if he want he Can change value by selecting dropdown button).
I have implemented Create,Retrieve and delete view and it is working fine but update operation is not working.Please find the html code which i am using.
*update.html*

```
<p>User information Update Form</p>
    <!--        <h5><span3>Note:</span3> For timing please use this format e.g 1.Morning Shift = <span2>6.30-3.30</span2> <br>2.Second Shift= <span1>3.30-12.30</span1><br>3.general Shift =<span4>9.00-6.00</span4></h5>-->
            <form method="post" class="post-form">
   
    
                {%csrf_token%}
    
                Ldap ID: <input type="text" name="ldap_id" value="{{oneuser.ldap_id}}"><br><br>
                Email ID: <input type="email" name="EmailID" value="{{oneuser.EmailID}}"><br><br>

                Company Name:<select name="Vendor_Company"
                <option value="{{oneuser.Vendor_Company}}">Genesys</option>
                <option value="{{oneuser.Vendor_Company}}">RMSI</option>
                <option value="{{oneuser.Vendor_Company}}">TCS</option>
                <option value="{{oneuser.Vendor_Company}}">Cognizant</option>
                <option value="{{oneuser.Vendor_Company}}">CTS</option></form></select>
                <br><br>
                Shift Timing:<select name="Shift_timing" choices=VENDOR_CHOICES

                <option value="{{oneuser.Shift_timing}}">9.00-6.00</option>
            <option value="{{oneuser.Shift_timing}}">6.30-3.30</option>
                <option value="{{oneuser.Shift_timing}}">12.30-3.30</option></div></select>
                <br><br>
    <!--            Shift Timing: <input type="text" name="Shift_timing" value="{{oneuser.Shift_timing}}"><br><br>-->
                Reason/justification for Change: <input type="textarea" name="Reason" value="{{oneuser.Reason}}"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Update Detail">
    
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I am moving the cursor over the update button I can see it is showing the correct url but when clicking for submit after changing a few fields from dropdown option it is redirecting to target page and but changes are not reflecting in db.

I think this problem is Coming because of implementing CHOICES option in model because without choices(dropdown) it is working fine.

Also would like to know if there is any way to get this done by using model based form instead of html(but problem is how to show content if we use model form).

*My views.py code*

```
def update_view(request,id):
        oneuser=ShiftChange.objects.get(id=id)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form=ShiftChangeForm(request.POST,instance=oneuser)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save(commit=True)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/alldata')
        return render(request,'apple/update.html',{'oneuser':oneuser})
```

*urls.py*

```
url(r'^update/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.update_view),
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a name to the url by doiing this :

```
url(r'^update/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.update_view, name='update_shift'),
```

and then in your template you have to the provide that URL NAME in the action attribute of the form tag so that the form hits the update url as needed, like shown :

```
<form method="post" class="post-form" action="{% url 'update_shift' oneuser.ldap_id %}">
```

Then you can print the form in your view to see the content like this:

```
print(form)
```

[Refer this django documentation for providing form URL in actions:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial04/)

Here onward you can perform the save. If you're not using model forms , you have to manually get data from the form and then saving it like this.

[And refer this stackoverflow for saving to db without using model form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32423401/save-form-data-in-django)

Comment: Hi Abhi.Thanks Can you please let me know error in above code as i have checked and found that url is redirecting and this problem is coming when i have inserted     SHIFT_CHOICES = (
        ('9.00-6.00','9.0-6.0'),
        ('6.30-3.30', '6.30-3.30'),
        ('12.30-3.30','12.30-3.30'),
    VENDOR_CHOICES = (
        ('genesys','Genesys'),
        ('rmsi', 'RMSI'),
        ('tcs','TCS'),
        ('Cognizant', 'Cognizant'),
        ('CTS', 'CTS.')
    )
So i wanted to know what is the error is there any other way to read record from db and also get the options (choices) in models.